# Warning: mkdir(): File exists

Tags: php

The file transferring to my upload folder is working well but I have a warning in *mkdir*. It says file exist but the picture and folder generates own name. I don't know what warning is determining.

```
include 'connect.php';

$dir = substr(uniqid(), -7); // Uniqid for subdirectory

$path = "uploads/$dir/"; // uploads/subdirectory/  // Make directory

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "kml");

$max_file_size = 2097152;

$count = 0;

// Loop $_FILES to execute all files

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            } elseif (!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)) {
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            } else { // No error found! Move uploaded files
                mkdir($path, 0700);
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $uniq_name = substr(uniqid(), -5) . '.' . $ext;
                $dest = $path . $uniq_name;

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest)) {
                    // more logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Warning is quite clear, you are creating directory which already exists. So, just change it to

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0700);
}
```

Comment: I used if (!file_exists($path)) { mkdir($path, 0700); } but it uploads 1 picture only even though I uploaded multiple. what should I do sir? sorry for my grammar. This is not my first language.

Comment: you must seperate the path to the folder, from the filename.. @user3199128

Answer (score 12):

Use PHP's `is_dir($path_to_dir)` for checking if a directory exists from before.

[Official documentation](https://www.php.net/is_dir)

Comment: This is problematic on unix systems because everything is a file, even directories.  If a file exists with the same name, said directory cannot be added.  So, simply checking if a "file" is a directory isn't sufficient.  Instead you should check `if(!file_exists($path))`.

Comment: @JacobThomason given your comment, how would you create a directory with the same name as an adjacent file? Is there a way of forcing mkdir() after a manual check for any pre-existing directories (but not files)?