# PHP 'mkdir(): File exists' when file size is too large?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making an upload script to upload multiple photos to one folder and simultaneously upload to another folder.

My problem is, I get the error: `mkdir(): File exists` when I'm uploading files that are over 2.5mb... I think.  My `phpinfo();` shows that my `post_max_size` is 8M and the `upload_max_filesize` is 40M. So I'm not sure why it's only doing this on large or many files.  If I upload smaller images (~1mb), then everything works fine.  But when I upload large files, I get that error.

caution: Wall of script...

Here are the functions:

```
<?PHP
    function makeFile($gallery_title, $gallery_date, $target_dir){
        $new_file = fopen($target_dir . "info.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = '<div class="info"><div class="title">'.$gallery_title.'</div><div class="date">'.$gallery_title.'</div><div class="enter">Enter</div></div>';
        fwrite($new_file, $txt);
        fclose($new_file);  
    }
    function resize($file, $width, $height, $target_dir, $new_name, $image_type){
        /* Get original image x y*/
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($file);
        /* calculate new image size with ratio */
        $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
        $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
        $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
        $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
        /* new file name */
        $path = $target_dir.$new_name;
        /* read binary data from image file */
        $imgString = file_get_contents($file);
        /* create image from string */
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
            0, 0,
            $x, 0,
            $width, $height,
            $w, $h);
        /* Save image */
        switch ($image_type) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($tmp, $path);
                break;
            default:
                exit;
                break;
        }
        return $path;
        /* cleanup memory */
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
    }
?>
```

And here's the script:

```
<?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $gallery_name = $_POST['galleryName'];
    $gallery_title = $_POST['galleryTitle'];
    $gallery_date = $_POST['galleryDate'];
    $target_dir = "../galleries/".$gallery_name."/";
    $target_dir_high = $target_dir."high/";
    $target_dir_low = $target_dir."low/";
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024000000; //1mb
    $count = 0;

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if (mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true) && mkdir($target_dir_high, 0777, true) && mkdir($target_dir_low, 0777, true)) {
            makeFile($gallery_title, $gallery_date, $target_dir); //Makes the info file
            // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
            foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
                if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                    $message[] = "$name has an error";
                    continue; // Skip file if any error found
                }          
                if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                    if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                        $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                        continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                    } else { // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                        $old_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$f];
                        $ext = end((explode(".", $old_name)));
                        $count_padded = sprintf("%02d", $count);
                        $new_name = $gallery_name."-".$count_padded.".".$ext;
                        $image_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$f];

                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f], resize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f], 1920, 1080, $target_dir_high, $new_name, $image_type))){
                            list($w, $h) = getimagesize($target_dir_high.$new_name);
                            $max_size = 500;
                            $long_side = max($w, $h);
                            $ratio = ($max_size/$long_side); //This is a percentage
                            $new_width = floor($w*$ratio);
                            $new_height = floor($h*$ratio);
                            $destImage = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                            $sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_dir_high.$new_name);
                            imagecopyresampled($destImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
                            imagejpeg($destImage, $target_dir_low.$new_name, 100);
                            imagedestroy($destImage);
                            imagedestroy($sourceImage);
                            if($count == 0){
                                copy($target_dir_low.$new_name, $target_dir.$new_name);
                            }
                            $count++;
                            echo $message = 'Congratulations!  The file '.$target_dir.$new_name.' was accepted.<br />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            die('This gallery exists.  Go back and rename.');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22032554/2079345

Comment: you say your are uploading multiple files? th combined size of all of them cannot exceed max_post_size, so in your case 8mb

Comment: You should use `basename($galleryName)` to initialize `$target_dir`. Imagine what happens if somebody enters a title that starts with (multiple) `../`.

Comment: `1024000000` bytes is not 1 MB (as it says in the comment). It is [`1024 MB`](https://www.google.com/search?q=1024000000+bytes+to+MB) or [`976.5625 MiB`](https://www.google.com/search?q=1024000000+bytes+to+MiB). Check [the difference between `MB` and `MiB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: @Augwa, Thank you - I think that might answer that question.  I'll do some tests on this.

Comment: @axiac, Fortunately, this is just for my own purposes. I won't enter any other name than what I need it to say, but I will keep that in mind if I need to make this public

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the dir already exists, use [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) for that. i.e.:

```
$dir = "/home/path/dir";
if(is_dir($dir))
  {
  echo ("dir $dir already exists");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("dir $dir doesn't exist");
  }
```

---

```
is_dir
```

> (PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> is_dir — Tells whether the filename is a directory
>   Returns `TRUE` if the filename exists and is a directory, `FALSE`
>   otherwise.

Comment: Pedro, Thank you - I think the issue is more of the fact that I'm reaching my `post_max_size` and it's causing this error to occur.  So if I were to put the code in that you're suggesting, I will just get the error "directory already exists" anyways.  I'm going to look more into `post_max_size`