# Kindly help me solve the mkdir() issue. on my wordpress website

Tags: php

I am getting the following error on my website:

> "Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /home/consttm8/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/application/functions/common.php on line 1112"

Can anybody guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0700);
}
```

Refer [Warning: mkdir(): File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032345/warning-mkdir-file-exists)